# MySQL DATE returns NULL

Tags: mysql, date

I have the following table structure:

```
uid     | ... | created | ...
int(10) | ... | int(10) | ...
```

`created` field is filled with timestamps; here are the results of query `SELECT created FROM mytable WHERE 1 LIMIT 5`:

```
created
----------
1308122243
1308122243
1308552690
1309247417
1309254571
```

But when I execute `SELECT DATE(created) FROM mytable WHERE 1 LIMIT 5`, I get strange NULL's:

```
DATE(created)
-------------
2013-08-12
2013-08-12
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Why that happens?

Comment: ur resultset for the query "SELECT created FROM mytable WHERE 1 LIMIT 5" is a bit confusing, plz paste the exact resultset

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're probably looking for

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)) FROM mytable WHERE 1 LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Yes, that was the case. I've found this out two minutes ago. But your answer will be accepted, of course :-)

Comment: FROM_UNIXTIME will return null if the date is greater than 2038-01-19. Here is a workaround http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811527/mysql-from-unixtime-after-2038-01-19

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you fundamentally misunderstand MySQL's date and time handling. Why are you storing dates as `int(10)` and not `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`?  That's just wrong.

Read the documentation. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

To summarize, the `int` is converted to a string, and the string is interpreted as a date representation.  1308122243 is interpreted as 13-08-12 plus some extra characters and so is converted to August 12, 2013. However 1308552690 is Aug 55, 2013, and thus invalid and thus `null`.

Comment: Storing timestamps in a DB is a very common practice. OP did just forget to make the conversion back to date.

Comment: @dystroy, nothing wrong with storing timestamps in the DB, just saying that they should be stored as `TIMESTAMP` rather than `int(10)`.  If you need fractional second accuracy that's another story, but here the OP isn't even using hours.

Comment: Also when reading other databases that you have no control over, it really helps to be able to convert the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(created) FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my own mistake, and solution was simple.

If you want to have an `int(10)` field be interpreted correctly as a timestamp, you should do `DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(created))` instead of just `DATE(created)`.

Answer (score 0):

did you try FROM_UNIXTIME?

```
SELECT DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME(`created`)) FROM mytable WHERE 1 LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

MY QUERY - `SELECT *,Year(date) AS Year FROM sql_basics.patients;`
is returning `NULL` in the Year `column`. the date is stored as `DD-MM-YYYY` in my database.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32917386)