# MySQL from_unixtime after 2038-01-19?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

We have dates stored as a unix timestamp. To allow a user to search for a certain date - based on his timezone-setting, we used to convert that timestamp inside the query, to make sure a search for "2012-05-03" will not find results of the prior / next day depending on which timezone the user has setup.

i.e. if a date is stored as `2012-05-03 23:00 (UTC)` A user with the proper timezone offset searching for `2012-05-04` should find this entry.

This is done like this at the moment:

```
CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(`javaTimeStampColumn`/1000),'+00:00','+00:00')
```

where ofc. the offsets are set depending on the users timezone.

The problem we are facing at the moment: Java successfully stores dates after the year `2038` as a unix-timestamp. The MySQL method `from_unixtime` however does not support any conversion of values greater than `2147483647` due to it's integer type limitation:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(2147483647); //2038-01-19 04:14:07

SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(2147483648); //null
```

The MySQL server itself is 64bit, but ofc. `FROM_UNIXTIME` would need to accept a long as argument.

I could not find a proper replacement by now, any hints?

---

We could ofc. load the timestamp as a Long and handle it in the application - But for *lazylaoding* we need to be able to convert it correctly during the query as well.

Comment: Any reason not to change the data type to `datetime`?

Comment: @juergend Yes, unfortunately the data is created by a part of the application where we can not change this. (3rd party library)

Comment: Did you try changing the data type of your timestamp column to `bigint`?

Comment: Are you using `timestamp` fields or `int`'s which have timestamps in them?

Comment: there is no built-in replacement. you can trivially store the 64bit timestamp as a `bigint`, but there won't be any built-in mysql functions to convert that to a date/time format.

Comment: it's `BIGINT(20)` columns.

Comment: There is a 10 year old [bug/feature request](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12654) for this.

Comment: @Vatev *Support for 64-bit TIMESTAMP data (or similar) will be part of a later release.* they said :-)

Comment: Yes, but you might need to wait until 2037 for it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A workaround might be to use `DATE_ADD`, but I'm not sure how it behaves performance-wise:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(0), INTERVAL 2147483647 SECOND); //2038-01-19 04:14:07
SELECT DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(0), INTERVAL 2147483648 SECOND); //2038-01-19 04:14:08
...
SELECT DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(0), INTERVAL 4147483647 SECOND); //2101-06-06 07:47:27
```

---

So for now, I'm using

```
...
CASE 
  WHEN `javaTimeStampColumn` > 2147483647 THEN
    CONVERT_TZ(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(0), INTERVAL `javaTimeStampColumn`/1000 SECOND),'+00:00','+00:00')
  ELSE  
    CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(`javaTimeStampColumn`/1000), '+00:00','+00:00')
END as ts
FROM table
...
```

which should minimize the impact on performance if there is any.

Comment: It seemed to solve the problem, until I stumbled across this (GMT+1 timezone):

`SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME( 1469230446 )` makes: 2016-07-23 **01**:34:06

`SELECT DATE_ADD( FROM_UNIXTIME( 0 ) , INTERVAL 1469230446
SECOND )` makes: 2016-07-23 **00**:34:06

Any idea?

Comment: @TamásMárton, use `CONVERT_TZ` with proper offsets. Unix-Time is always UTC. `DATE_ADD` is using your Timezone of `GMT+1`, so you need to fix this.

Comment: Thanks, setting the client timezone to '+00:00' fixed it really.

Comment: @TamásMárton that's an option as well. (I also prefer to have the "Server" running in UTC-Timezone no matter where it is actually deployed)

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree. Unfortunately, this is a shared web hosting with configuration limitations (: